# HTML5 + CSS3 layout - Vertical centering of picture

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to Vertical centering picture on my page
i tried few scripts & styles but none of them worked

my page is:
[TEST.esc.bugs3.com](http://TEST.esc.bugs3.com)

I'm trying to Center the "Arrow" pic on the left & right sides to the center of the main pic
today all i get is the pic is always on the "TOP" of the DIV & i wish to put in in center

Note: I don't wanna use fix size as PX i wish to make it with 50%
like main pic is the 100% height and the arrow will be show on 50% of it

[Layout - how i wish it will look like](http://temp.esc.bugs3.com/demo.JPG)

thanks for the help :)

Edit:
thanks for the answers 
but i need the side div (side box) to be  Vertical centered to the main div (center box)

the main pic size is not fixed (every media will have different size - so i cant use PX as position

Comment: Show your code not a link, I doubt anyone would want to keep jumping back and forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the css for Sidepanel class as below

```
    .SidePanel {
      width: 5%;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
      background-color: green;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 Flexbox for modern Browsers: Here's [Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for it.

```
.center-both{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  height: 350px; 
  background: LightSeaGreen; 
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k72uf/)

Read this article for more on flexbox: http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2014/05/css-flexbox-explained-with-examples.html

If you want to support old browsers like IE7/IE8 then use `display: table-cell;` property to place the content vertically center.

Comment: thanks for the answer

I already try that one - im trying to avoid "FIXED" size elemets

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code For Your Pic:

```
.pic{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -(HEIGHT/2)
}
```

Which HEIGHT is Your Picture's height in Pixels.

**Update 1**
Your Container Should Have A Specific Height And Have A CSS Property: `Position: (Relative|Absolute|Fixed)`